# Is there C# WinForms API for Precision Touchpad scrolling gesture?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10, touchpad

I am using a WinForms control named [TreeViewAdv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/). My laptop has a Microsoft Precision Touchpad. Two-finger scrolling works rather well (but not as good as that of Macbook) with modern applications such as Microsoft Edge. But it does not work well with TreeViewAdv. Two-finger scrolling is unresponsive and jerky. TreeViewAdv scrolls moderately well when using the mouse wheel.

Unfortunately, the project seems to be abandoned and not actively developed. However, since TreeViewAdv is an open-source library, I can edit it myself. Is there any API to make a WinForms control respond to the two-finger scrolling well as Microsoft Edge does?

Comment: Precision TouchPad lacks API right now, vote here to let Microsoft know we need it: https://aka.ms/Uun1l5